# How to resolve central.maven.org: Unknown host central.maven.org in Maven Project?

Tags: java, maven, jar, package, war

Please find the below logs :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project hospital: Could not resolve dependencies for project 
com.project_name.test.web:hospital:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at 
com.example.test:example-child:jar:1.1.12-SNAPSHOT: Failed to read artifact descriptor for 
com.example.test:example-child:jar:1.1.12-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact 
com.example.test:example-parent:pom:1.1.12-SNAPSHOT from/to maven-central
(http://central.maven.org/maven2/): central.maven.org: Unknown host central.maven.org -> [Help 1]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That looks like an **old** version of maven. I'm pretty sure the default central repo uses https now. What version of maven are you using?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I am using Apache Maven 3.5.2 Could you please tell me the resolution?

Comment: Try upgrading maven. The current release is [3.6.3](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi) and "http://central.maven.org/maven2/" is now "https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2"

Comment: You are probably inside a company network and have a proxy problem.

Comment: @JFMeier Yes Exactly. How to resolve it ?

Comment: You need to talk to the admin to find out how to configure the proxy.

Answer (score 0):

This failes likely due to an artifact downloaded earlier (in my case .m2/repository/org/geotools/geotools/19.1/geotools-19.1.pom) containing this as a specific repo, maybe even retrieved from a thirdparty repo.

Check your local artifacts for references to the repository, e.g. by this brute force approach:

```
grep -nr "central.maven.org" ~/.m2/repository/
```

Replacing/removing the dependency solved the issue.